# How to Copy Column data from one table to another table in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables

1. users
2. activity

I have a column in the `users` table which is named as `activity_date`. Now, I want to add that column's data to my Activity table.
For this, I introduce a new field in the `Activity` table named `activity_date`.

I am using this query to copy data from `users` table to `activity` table

```
DB::statement('UPDATE `activity` (`activity_date`) SELECT `activity_date` FROM `users` WHERE `users.id` = `activity.user_id`');
```

When I run the migration, It returns an error

```
[PDOException]                                                                      
SQLSTATE[233652]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause'
```

I never tried this before. May someone please guide me on how to do this? Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: The backticks are used to _quote_ identifiers, so that any special characters they might contain, _lose_ that special meaning. You told the database, the column was actually named  `users.id` – which it isn’t. You have _two_ identifiers here, one for the table, one for the column. They need to be quoted each on their own.

Comment: The correct syntax would be `\`users\`.\`id\``

Answer (score 1):

you should join your tables then use DB::raw

```
DB::table('activity')->join('users','activity.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->update(['activity.activity_date'=>DB::raw('users.activity_date')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update users set activity_date=(SELECT activity_date from activity where id='1')where id='1'
```

This will take acitivity_date with ID=1 from table activity, and update acitivity_date in users table where user id=1.

tables:
(users): id, name, activity_date
(activity) id, activity_date

Comment: You can add some more description